# Need Jquery Help in fixing modal popup

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

What i Need is?

1. on `click me` i need a popup with `save` button.
2. on `save` button click i need another confirmation popup after main popup closed

What i'm getting is?

i'm able to get 1 step and on save click i'm getting confirmation popup.
problem is when i clicked on `x` icon, then also i'm getting confirmation popup. i need confirmation popup only on save button. not on clicking `x` icon.

wired situation?

I'm not getting confirmation popup on first time `x` click.

```js
$(document).on('click','.closeMyModal',function(){
  $("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    //alert('Hidden');
    $('#employeekipsave').modal('show');
    //alert('visible');
  });
})
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Click Me</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-large" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Employee KPI's</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         Dummy Text Comes Here
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>-->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary closeMyModal" data-dismiss="modal" >Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="employeekipsave">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center success-popup">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><h5 class="text-success">Are you sure you want save Employee KPI's?</h5><button type="button" class="btn defaultBtn btn-sm  btn-defult" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">No</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm defaultBtn" data-dismiss="modal" id="employeeKpiSuccess" style="margin-left:5px;" >Yes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){ });` registers an event-listener that will run whenever the modal gets hidden, you will notice you are only getting the strange behaviour if you have already clicked on the Save button, because it then registers this event listener. Remove it, and it will work 100%.

Added the event listener for when the second modal is about to be shown to add the class `modal-open` to the body tag, which usually gets added automatically, but seems to be a bug which happens when you show a modal while the transition for the fading out of the first modal is still happening. ( The modal-open class gets added when showing the second modal, but after that the fade transition of the first modal completes, removing it from the body tag )

Edit: This also does not work, event firing with the fade transition seems buggy
removing the fade class from the first modal solves the scrollbar issue.

```js
$(document).on('click','.closeMyModal',function(){
    //alert('Hidden');
    $('#employeekipsave').modal('show');

    //alert('visible');
});

/* Does not solve issue with scrollbars, see Edit note above
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#employeekipsave").on('show.bs.modal', function() {
        $('body').addClass("modal-open");
    });
});
*/
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Click Me</a>
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-large" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Employee KPI's</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         Dummy Text Comes Here
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>-->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary closeMyModal" data-dismiss="modal" >Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="employeekipsave">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center success-popup">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><h5 class="text-success">Are you sure you want save Employee KPI's?</h5><button type="button" class="btn defaultBtn btn-sm  btn-defult" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">No</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm defaultBtn" data-dismiss="modal" id="employeeKpiSuccess" style="margin-left:5px;" >Yes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Heinrich. Here is test URL. when i go through the same process it is adding padding to the broswer. Please go through the URL. http://saviance-fraud.com/modal-popup.html.

Comment: It is working fine in some scenarios where the browser doesn't have scroll. if the browser has scroll already then it's is not working. that's the reason i tried hidden bs modal event

Comment: Looks like it might still not be working, something strange with the order/event firing of bootstrap modals. Removing the fade class from your first modal fixes this.

Comment: Yes Heinrich, Even i'm not getting any solutions to fix this. It is necessary for me.

Comment: So you need the fade effect? If so, a crude solution might be a timeout based one where you apply the modal-open class to the body after a set amount of milliseconds ( around 300 should do ), if by tonight this question still open I will edit my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124864/discussion-between-charantej-golla-and-heinrich-henning).

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger to open the second modal after clicking the save button by adding the attributes `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#employeekipsave"` to the save button. In this case you don't need any additional JavaScript code.

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Click Me</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-large" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Employee KPI's</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Dummy Text Comes Here
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>-->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary closeMyModal" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#employeekipsave">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="employeekipsave">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body clearfix">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center success-popup">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><h5 class="text-success">Are you sure you want save Employee KPI's?</h5><button type="button" class="btn defaultBtn btn-sm  btn-defult" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">No</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm defaultBtn" data-dismiss="modal" id="employeeKpiSuccess" style="margin-left:5px;" >Yes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your solution solution the modal showed up by clicking on the x because the `hidden.bs.modal` event is fired when clicking on x.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Thomas. But i'm calling 'hidden.bs.modal' on a button click. not on x mark.

Comment: Yes but you register a handler on the hidden event which calls $('#employeekipsave').modal('show') so each time your first modal (#myModal) is hidden the second modal (#employeekipsave) is shown.

What happens on the button click is not a call to the function which opens the second modal but an event registration to show the second modal each time the first one hides.

Comment: Thomas, Your idea is working fine when the browser has no scroll. Please go through the below URL. U will get idea what i'm saying. http://saviance-fraud.com/modal-popup.html

Answer (score 0):

You could simply close the current modal and then open the second modal.

Example.

```
$(document).on('click','.closeMyModal',function(){
  $("#myModal").modal('hide');
  $('#employeekipsave').modal('show');
})
```

Comment: I tried this Dimal. It is causing Padding issues. every time i click on save button it is adding padding-right: 17px to the browser.